# How to use pretty debugging printers to see Eigen objects in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, eigen

I am trying to see the contents of an **Eigen** vector in the **Locals and Expressions** window of the **QtCreator**:

[image]

I see that it is a vector with 10 components:

[image]

but when I click it open I get:

[image]

I tried to use [this script to do the trick](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/12a658962d4e/debug/gdb/printers.py). I saved it along with an empty **__init__.py** file into folder **~/Scripts/Eigen** and created the **.gdbinit** file:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/martin/Scripts/Eigen')
from printers import register_eigen_printers
register_eigen_printers (None)
end
```

I restarted **QtCreator** and nothing changed. I have checked the **"read .gdbinit at startup"** option in QtCreator settings and still nothing.

What is worrying me is that I know that in the past the viewing of Eigen objects worked **without me meddling with some scripts**.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

I am using:

**gcc version 4.8.1** 
**Ubuntu 13.10**
**gdb 7.6.1-ubuntu**
**Qt Creator 3.0.0**
**Based on Qt 5.2.0**

and I am compiling using these flags:

```
g++ -c -pipe -gdwarf-4 -fvar-tracking-assignments -g 
    -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG
```

**EDIT:**

as @ggael suggested, I tried to run the **gdb directly**:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/martin/Projects/TestGrounds/test 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py", line 59, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py", line 59, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
```

And then:

```
(gdb) print vec
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> 'map' object is not subscriptable: 
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> 'map' object is not subscriptable: 
$1 = {<Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >> = {<Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >> = {<Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >> = {<Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, double, double, false>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 3>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 1>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 0>> = {<Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    m_storage = {m_data = 0x804e020, m_rows = 10}}, <No data fields>}
```

Please, could you explain what does this mean? What is **libstdcxx**?

Comment: Boy wouldn't that be nice!?!  =)

Comment: It works nicely for we with QtCreator 2.8.1/Qt4.8.6/gcc-4.8/gdb-7.6 (Debian). First, make sure it works when using gdb directly.

Comment: Also, the `.gdbinit` must be in your home (`/home/martin/.gdbinit`).

Comment: What of your used tools (gcc, ...) have you changed from the day when it had worked until now?

Comment: @falkb I think I just upgraded Ubuntu and the debugging window got broken completely. I then installed the latest QtCreator and I got the partial results that I have now.

Comment: @ggael Yes, I have the `.gdbinit` in the path you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was probably in the debugger itself. I tried out many combinations of

1. load \ do not load `.gdbinit`
2. load \ do not load system pretty printers
3. use \ don't use code model
4. -gdwarf-x compiler flags

and none of this really mattered. Then I tried a fresh install of **Ubuntu 12.04** with old **GDB 7.4** and a brand new **QtCreator 3.0.1** and it worked! I got the same results for 
**gcc 4.6**, **gcc 4.7** and **gcc 4.8.1**.

Then I tried the newest **GDB 7.7** on **Ubuntu 13.10** and again it worked, while **GDB 7.5, GDB 7.6** did not work.

Also a strange thing, `std::shared_ptr` is correctly viewed **only** in **QtCreator 3.0.1**.

`std::multimap` is not pretty printed in any configuration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> vec(4, 3);
    std::map<int, std::string> map =        {{1,"one"},{2,"two"},{3,"three"}};
    std::multimap<int, std::string> multi = {{1,"one"},{2,"two"},{3,"three"}};

    Eigen::VectorXd vector = Eigen::VectorXd::Constant(3, 3.14);
    std::shared_ptr<Eigen::VectorXd> pointer(new Eigen::VectorXd(vector));

    std::cout << vector << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in `/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py`. Make sure you have the lastest version of the gcc4.8 packages, it might be that this issue is already fixed in unbuntu (it is fixed in debian). See this bug [entry](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=701935#18). In the last ressort you can patch this file so that it searches in the right location.

Comment: So is it a problem in the gcc? Should I upgrade to 4.8.2?

Comment: Upgrading might indeed fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However the problem was probably in the version of GDB I was using. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22055750/1097451

Answer (score 2):

Works for me as expected. The output looks like

```
vec (10 x 1), ColumnMajor   Eigen::VectorXd
    [0] 3.1400000000000001  double
    [1] 3.1400000000000001  double
    [2] 3.1400000000000001  double
    [3] 3.1400000000000001  double
    [4] 3.1400000000000001  double
    [5] 3.1400000000000001  double
    [6] 3.1400000000000001  double
    [7] 3.1400000000000001  double
    [8] 3.1400000000000001  double
    [9] 3.1400000000000001  double
```

Make sure to use Qt Creator's own pretty-printing system by removing(!) the checkmark in Tools/Options/Debugger/GDB/Load system pretty printers. You also don't need the code you put into your .gdbinit in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the issue. I don't think it had something to do with the QtCreator settings, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22055750/1097451