# Trouble printing Eigen types in gdb using python extension

Tags: c++, gdb, eigen

I'd like to print Eigen matrices and vectors in gdb, and so I added the extension to do so found here: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/12a658962d4e/debug/gdb/printers.py

When I try to call print on some Eigen type in ddd, however, I get the following error:

```
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> 'map' object is not subscriptable: 
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> 'map' object is not subscriptable: 
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> 'map' object is not subscriptable:
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340866/how-to-use-pretty-debugging-printers-to-see-eigen-objects-in-qtcreator) I checked that my gcc version is 4.8.2 and my gdb version is 7.7.1, so neither of those are the problem.

Any ideas on how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: Which python version? Mine is 2.7.8, and works correctly with Debian's gdb 7.7.1+dfsg-5.

Comment: My python version is 2.7.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make sure that 2.7.6 is the version that gdb uses by making the following check from it?

1. Start gdb.
2. Type:

   import sys

   print (sys.version)
3. End with `CTRL+D`

Comment: This is the output I get: 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:08:40)

Comment: So that's the difference then. The script uses python 2 syntax, whether your gdb interpreter uses python 3. It has to be adapted to work in your environment. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800481/python-map-object-is-not-subscriptable

Comment: Fixed, thanks! I was hoping it would print Matlab-style rather than element by element, but I guess there's my reason to learn a little python...

Comment: I used 2to3 tool (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/2to3.html) to convert eigen-3.2.5/debug/gdb/printers.py and resolved the problem.